# XML Parsing error: Extra content at the end of the document

Tags: xml, parsing

I am getting this error in my xml file: `XML Parsing error: Extra content at the end of the document`

I am using Notepad++ and it shows the second word in red in the header tags `<ABC BLAH>hello</ABC BLAH>` - it shows the **BLAH** in red. Because of this, I assume the problem is in the whitespace in the header tags and throws a validation error at that line. How do I resolve this?

This is the xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<rows>
    <row>
        <Order>1</Order>
        <Requirements>ABC</Requirements>
        <Testing Procedures>blah blah </Testing Procedures> 
        <Assessment Observations / Comments>blah blah</Assessment Observations / Comments> <-- throws Parsing error at this line.
    </row>
</rows>
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
<Testing Procedures="">blah blah </Testing Procedures>
```

Can't have spaces in element names.

```
<Assessment Observations="" / Comments>blah blah</Assessment Observations / Comments>
```

Also this has multiple errors. Maybe you meant this ? :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<rows>
  <row>
    <Order>1</Order>
    <Requirements>ABC</Requirements>
    <TestingProcedures foo=" ">blah blah </TestingProcedures>
    <Assessment Observations="/ Comments>blah blah"/>
    <Assessment Observations=" / Comments"/>
  </row>
</rows>
```

You have multiple errors. Can't really tell what you are trying to do.

OK .xml 101:

XML doesn't permit spaces in element names.

If you don't close the element name you can specify attributes like this.

```
<foo bar="I am an attribute" lol="Me too"> Here you can specify text, or other elements </foo>
```

In addition if an element doesn't contain another one , or a text you can use the shorthand notation

```
<foo attribute="bar"/>
```

I suggest you read some basic [tutorial](http://www.w3schools.com/xml/) for this.

Comment: Thanks for your quick reply. Do I have to add `=""` in every element name with space?

Comment: that's actually a header tag converted from excel file. That's one element with the forward slash `Assessment Observation/Comment` with the data "blah". I know it has errors and I would like to resolve it.

Comment: @fuz3d Then you should check out how a correct excel header tag look like and adapt your .xml to fit it.

Comment: FailedDev, thanks for your help. I have marked your answer. By the way, I am not an expert, but you should take a look at this site: http://www.w3fools.com/