# Error occurs when XML syntax checking DTD file

Tags: xml, syntax, notepad++, dtd

I have a problem regarding my DTD-file. When I do a syntax check in Notepad++ this appears - is there someone who knows what this means and what I possibly need to change in my DTD-file?

Thanks for the help

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/q8atx.png)

Comment: Do not post images for text errors. Copy the error string here.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [XML Parsing error: Extra content at the end of the document](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8189117/xml-parsing-error-extra-content-at-the-end-of-the-document) or https://stackoverflow.com/q/34344522/372239